# regex finding number after first ocurance of substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence:

`"Fourth-quarter 2021 net earnings per share (EPS) of $1.26, compared with 2020 EPS of $1.01; Fourth-quarter 2021 adjusted EPS of $1.11, down 25.5 percent compared with 2020 adjusted EPS of $1.49"`

and would like to get number $1.11 after the first substring "adjusted EPS".

The best regex formula I could come with is:

```
re.search("^.*Adjusted EPS.*?(\$\d+.\d+).*", text,re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

but this gives me number $1.49 after second occurrence of "adjusted EPS".

How can I modify the search so I get the number $1.11?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is greedy regex which you use just in the beginning:

```
^.*Adj ...
```

`^` means the start of the string. Being greedy, `.*` "eats" as much characters as possible up until the last "adjusted EPS"

There're two solutions here, either make it non-greedy (i.e. lazy) `^.*?Adj ...`, or remove `^.*` completely - I see no use of it here

Comment: Note it's `^.*adj...`. Nor does `.*` at the end serve a purpose. Perhaps `\badjusted EPS\b.*?(\$\d+.\d{2})`, the word boundaries to avoid matching, for example, `"readjusted EPS"` (probably not needed but does no harm). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dDH5J/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex string should work.
`/adjusted EPS of ?(\$\d+.\d+)/g`

Input:

```
Fourth-quarter 2021 net earnings per share (EPS) of $1.26, compared with 2020 
EPS of $1.01; Fourth-quarter 2021 adjusted EPS of $1.11, down 25.5 percent 
compared with 2020 adjusted EPS of $1.49
```

Output:
adjusted EPS of $1.11,
adjusted EPS of $1.49

Edit: Remove the `g` at the end of the Regex string to only find one match.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern which looks for "adjusted EPS" and only allows one "$" between it and the end of the line.

```
/adjusted EPS[^\$]+(\$\d+\.\d+)[^\$]+$/gm
```

the pattern without the endings is

```
adjusted EPS[^\$]+(\$\d+\.\d+)[^\$]+$
```